# Implement VariableSize items in GridView with drag and drop functionality

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have implement a GridView In which I have binded user controls as items:

```
grdVwWidget.Items.Add(userControl);
```

Each user control has its own height and width. The Gridview has drag and drop functionality:

```
<GridView
        x:Name="grdVwWidget"
        CanDragItems="True"
        CanReorderItems="True"
        AllowDrop="True"
       ItemsPanel="{StaticResource grdVwWidgetItemPanel}"
/>

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="grdVwWidgetItemPanel">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Currently the items are displayed but not wrapped and arranged properly.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this link you are looking? http://wpfplayground.blogspot.in/2013/03/different-sized-tile-items-in-winrt.html

Comment: I am looking for the same but I can't use VariableSizeWrap grid since I am using drag and drop functionality and VariableSizeWrap grid doesn't support that.